# How can I write a regular expression to match ftp, ftps or sftp?

Tags: php, regex, validation

I'm doing some URL validation and want to match http, https, ftp, ftps, sftp etc.

So far I have `/(https?|ftps?)/`.. If I use `s?ftps?` it'll match ftp, ftps, sftp *and* sftps.

What's the best way to get around this? (sftps is not a valid URL scheme)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(ht|f)tps?|sftp/
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

This should cover all your bases...

```
/(ht|f)tps?|sftp/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/^(?:ht|f)tps?|sftp/
```

or

```
/^(?!sftps)(?:https?|s?ftps?)/
```